# jQuery Masonry with Django for loop

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-masonry

jQuery Masonry doesn't work with Django templating tags like this:

```
{% for memes in memes %}
      <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ image.image }}" id="{{ image.pk }}"/>
      <div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I set up an identical instance when with the divs are spelled out:

```
<div class="masonryImage">
  <img src="/static/media/images/2012/1018/inspirational-quote-michelangelo-sunrise.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="masonryImage">
  <img src="/static/media/images/2012/1018/inspirationalpercent20quotespercent204_4341.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

My JS:

```
  <script>
$(function(){

var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.masonryImage'
  });
});

});
</script>
```

Here is the rendered HTML (with the for template tag). I have tried removing the id's in case they were problems (didn't work):

```
<div id="container">

      <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="/static/media/images/2012/1018/inspirational-quote-michelangelo-sunrise.jpg" id="9"/>
      <div>

      <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="/static/media/images/2012/1018/inspirationalpercent20quotespercent204_4341.jpg" id="7"/>
      <div>

      <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="/static/media/images/2012/1018/002.gif" id="6"/>
      <div>

      <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="/static/media/images/2012/1018/tumblr_mc1jac0bkn1rnn6wqo1_500.png" id="4"/>
      <div>

      <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="/static/media/images/2012/1018/inspirational-quotes30.jpg" id="2"/>
      <div>

      <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="/static/media/images/2012/1018/inspirational-quotes20.jpg" id="1"/>
      <div>

</div>
```

**Update**
I have tried putting the {% for %} images under the same container and then added 'spelled-out' divs.  This causes the {% for %} images to render VERTICALLY (with no masonry) and the spelled-out divs to render with masonry.

Is there a better way to template this AND have jQuery Masonry work?

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work with Django template tags?  Those tags render before the javascript even does anything.  Are you getting some form of error?

Comment: Like @Gromer said: What does the source in the browser look like?

Comment: Yes, when under tags, jQuery Masonry places large gaps between images. When the divs are spelled out (as in the second example), jQuery Masonry works well. Honestly, I'm not 100% sure why this is the case.

Comment: The source in the browser looks identical to when it is spelled out. I basically set up both scenarios holding the {% for %} template tags constant. jQuery Masonry creates big gaps when there is the {% for %} tag

Comment: Are you trying to say jQuery Masonry is mad because of whitespace between the divs?

Comment: Also, post the rendered HTMl as well as the javascript you're using to setup Masonry.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Gromer. I have edited the orig post with the rendered HTML and the JS snippet. Any of your insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I have put the {% for %} images with the spelled-out div images. The {% for %} images render vertically without masonry while the spelled-out divs render with masonry.

Comment: Why you need Django? Do you have a jsfiddle or online example where one can examine what's wrong?

Comment: I need Django because of the template tags. I am basically sending context from the backend

Comment: If you are saying the output from Django is the same as the static content that works, then that means there is a javascript error elsewhere that is upsetting Masonry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly error,

I went into jQuery and printed out console logs. The problem was that I missed a trailing / in the div.

Face palm.